# Jsoup method header(String, String) is undefined for the type Connection.KeyVal

Tags: java, connection, jsoup

I am using Jsoup Version 1.9.2 and have the following code:

```
 public static String reQuest(String tUri, org.jsoup.Connection.Method Met, String postData) throws IOException {
    Response res = null;

    try {
      res = Jsoup.connect( tUri )
              .ignoreContentType( true )
              .followRedirects( true )
              .cookies( HandleSession.COOKIES )
        .data( postData )
        .header( "X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest" )
        .method( Met )
        .timeout( 10000 )
        .execute();
      Util.log.finest( tUri );
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return res == null ? null : res.body();
  }
```

The error is in this line:

```
.header( "X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest" )
```

it says:

**The method header(String, String) is undefined for the type Connection.KeyVal**

but jsoup documentation says, that this method is available with this parameters:

https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.Response.html

I already used exactly this code with a former version of jsoup.

What is wrong with it?

Comment: Ah, in Jsoup 1.9.2  the request body has to be set by using .requestBody instead of .data. Im so sorry, did not see it.

Comment: you should add this as the answer

Answer (score -1):

In Jsoup 1.9.2 the request body has to be set by using .requestBody instead of .data. Im so sorry, did not see it.